# select rowid Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, toad, rowid

Im trying to display the rowid pseudocolumn, but something strange happened,
This is my query

```
select rowid, rowid||'', rowid r from dual
```

output:

```
ROWID||''           R
AAAAECAABAAAAgiAAA  AAAAECAABAAAAgiAAA
```

So why cant display `rowid` without alias or not concatenated with something else ? Any explanation ?
I used Toad and Oracle 10g.

Comment: I think it a TOAD internal processing issue. Try with simple SQLplus

Comment: @Wernfried I dont have other query tool, but I tried with SQLFiddle.com and its worse, error message appear when querying `rowid`, if you are sure, plz try it with SQLplus and ill accept your answer.

Comment: SQL Developer can be a bit odd too - wraps the value to the length of alias (or 5 with no alias), without a column setting. SQL\*Plus is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [seems to be a Toad setting](http://toad.10940.n7.nabble.com/Displaying-ROWID-in-DATA-GRID-td21436.html) to hide the pseudocolumn:

> In your data grid, mouse-right-click - SELECT COLUMNS
>
> Enable 'ROWID'
>
> You also have -
>
> Toad - View - Options - Data Grids - Data - Display - 'Show ROWID in
>   editable grids'

It's displayed in SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, and other clients.

Comment: It might be also OCI related. There is an option where OCI implicitly returns ROWID as 0th column, even if the query does not return it. Maybe TOAD is somehow confused, when the query itself returns ROWID.

Comment: @ibre5041 - I think the setting is to suppress display of that implicit OCI column; which is understandable but not helpful if you explicitly include it in your select list.